# How to write script using actual csv files rather than stringIO

Tags: python, csv, rename, import-csv

How can I write the following script below which renames and reorders column headers using imported string IO into the format of using actual csv files as the dataset is too large.

```
from io import StringIO
from collections import OrderedDict
import csv

mystr = StringIO("""A;B;C;D
1;2;3;4
5;6;7;8""")

order = ['B', 'C', 'A', 'D']

# define renamed columns via dictionary
renamer = {'C': 'C2'}

# define column names after renaming
new_cols = [renamer.get(x, x) for x in order]

# replace mystr as open(r'file.csv', 'r')
with mystr as fin, open(r'C:\temp\out.csv', 'w', newline='') as fout:

# define reader / writer objects
reader = csv.DictReader(fin, delimiter=';')
writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=';')

# write new header
writer.writerow(new_cols)

# iterate reader and write row
for item in reader:
    writer.writerow([item[k] for k in order])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your primary issue with your code is that the `with` code needs indented in order for it to work.  The following is minor alterations to your code that lets it read from one csv, and write to another:

```
from io import StringIO
from collections import OrderedDict
import csv

order = ['B', 'C', 'A', 'D']

# define renamed columns via dictionary
renamer = {'C': 'C2'}

# define column names after renaming
new_cols = [renamer.get(x, x) for x in order]

# replace mystr as open(r'file.csv', 'r')
with open('C:\tmp\in.csv') as fin, open(r'C:\temp\out.csv', 'w', newline='') as fout:
    # define reader / writer objects
    reader = csv.DictReader(fin, delimiter=';')
    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=';')

    # write new header
    writer.writerow(new_cols)

    # iterate reader and write row
    for item in reader:
        writer.writerow([item[k] for k in order])
```

Comment: That would indicate that your input file/data doesn't have 'A' as a column.